# Username already exists, please check for available options during sign up

Tags: angular, angular4-forms, login-control

I am creating an angular app in which a user can register. But while registering I request him for some details like email, mobile number and all. Also, a username which he can choose. But here I want to do a check on the username as soon as he entered and display an error like," this username already exists in our database".

I have mysql database and front end with angular 4. 
I am new to this angular development, please help me how can i do this?

Here is a sample image for google sign up,
[image]

Answer (score 10):

You can use [AsyncValidator](https://alligator.io/angular/async-validators/) and [asynchronous-validation-in-angulars](http://fiyazhasan.me/asynchronous-validation-in-angulars-reactive-forms-control/)

Or my implementation:

Form initialize:

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
  username: [{value: null, disabled: false}, 
    [Validators.required, this.validateUsername()]]
})
```

Custom validator:

```
private validateUsername(): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} => {
      this.someServiceWorkingWithDatabase.checkUsername(control)
        .subscribe(
          ({data}) => {
            let res: string = data;
            if (res === control.value) {
              return {'alreadyExist': true};
            } else {
              return null
            }
          },
          (error) => {
            console.log(error);
          }
        )
    }
}
```

Template:

```
<div class="formError" *ngIf="this.form['controls']
  .username.hasError('alreadyExist')">
    *this username already exists in our database</div>
```

Comment: The validator function is being called. But how do we tell the form control to go into error state in case 'alreadyExist': true is returned.

Answer (score 1):

Now i will create student form with unique emailid using **angular, nodejs and mongodb**

**HTML FILE**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4">Email</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" formControlName="s_email" #s_email (change)="emailCheckUnique()" />
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="angForm.controls['s_email'].invalid && (angForm.controls['s_email'].dirty || angForm.controls['s_email'].touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
    <div *ngIf="angForm.controls['s_email'].errors.required">
      E-mail is required.
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="angForm.controls['s_email'].errors.email">
      Enter Valid E-mail 
    </div>
  </div>  
  <div *ngIf="emailAlredyExist != ''" class="alert alert-danger">
    {{emailAlredyExist}} 
  </div>
```

**Component FIle**

```
emailAlredyExist = "";
emailCheckUnique() {
this.ss.emailCheckUnique(this.angForm.controls['s_email'].value).subscribe(res => {
  this.studentEmailcheck = res;
  if (this.studentEmailcheck.length > 0) {
    this.emailAlredyExist = "Email Alredy Exist";
  }
  else{
    this.emailAlredyExist = "";
  }
});
}
```

**Service File**

```
emailCheckUnique(email) {
return this
          .http
          .get(`${this.uri}/email/${email}`);
}
```

**Nodejs Router File**

```
studentRoutes.route('/email/:email').get(function (req, res) {
let email = req.params.email;
Student.find({s_email: email}, function (err, student){
res.json(student);
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With angular 13 in html call on change or input event so when you leave the tab it show message.

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email" tabindex="3" required="required"
        (input)="onChangeValidateUser($event.target.value)"
        ngModel
        email
        #email="ngModel">
        <span class="help-block" *ngIf="!email.valid && email.touched"> *Please enter valid email.</span>
</div>
```

In components.ts

```js
onChangeValidateUser(email: string) {
    // console.log(email);
    if (email) {
        this.apiRequestService.validateUser(email)
            .subscribe(responseData => {
                if(responseData['status'] === 1) {
                    //  this.email ='';    
                }
                console.log(responseData['message']);
             });
        }
}
```

service.ts

```js
validateUser(email: string) {
    console.log(email);
    return this.http.get<string>(
        'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/validate',
        {
            headers: new HttpHeaders({'Accept':'application/json'}),
            params: new HttpParams().set('email',email)
        });
}
```

Now, we will use Laravel8 for api and mysql as database.
api.php define route

controller.php

```php
Route::get('/users/validate',[UsersController::class,'checkUser']);
public function checkUser(Request $request){
    // error_log('Some message here.');
    $user = users::where('email', '=', $request->email)->first();
    if ($user === null) {
        // user doesn't exist
        return response()->json(['status'=> 0,'message' => 'User does not exists','data' => $user ]);;
    } else {
        return response()->json(['status'=> 1,'message' => 'User exists','data' => $user->email ]);
    }
    //   return DB::table('users')
    //   ->where('email', '=', $request->email)
    //   ->get();
}
```